# Using the API licenseCloud, and incoporating it with your aps and web pages

Tags: licensecloud-api

I tried using the licenseCloud API but was una ble to get it right, the only guess I came to was the fact that I obtained an XML and a link to that XML "https://secure.licenseapi.com/?token=73af9d231e354e2c9ba30a72fdc68341b88613c1&sku=EXAMPLE&license=e59d6fd6629044f4ace4", so I took the link, placed in a textbox and on a buttonclick fires.

```
XDocument csvDocument = XDocument.Load(txtActivateFromSite.Text);
        var samples = csvDocument.Descendants("license")
                     .Select(el => new
                     {
                         Id = el.Element("dashed").Value,
                         Selected = el.Element("status").Value,
                         Selected1 = el.Element("trial").Value,
                         Selected2 = el.Element("expires").Value,
                         Selected3 = el.Element("activated").Value
                     });
        string dashed = ""; string status = ""; string trial = ""; string expires = ""; string activated = "";
        foreach (var sample in samples)
        {
            dashed = sample.Id;
            status = sample.Selected;
            trial = sample.Selected1;
            expires = sample.Selected2;
            activated = sample.Selected3;
        }
        MessageBox.Show("your Application has been activate with License Number " + dashed + " on " + activated + " expires on "+
                         expires + ".");
```

Somehow I incoporated it to get something, please anymore ideas on how to use licensecloud

Answer (score 0):

Appears you've forgotten the CMD parameter on your link:

```
&cmd=activate...
```

Also, you can download some sample code here (in PHP). Will give you a good idea on how to get it to work:

https://www.licensecloud.com/2015/04/10/licensecloud-protect-web-page/